# How to pass datepicker value into a textbox with onclick function at datepicker items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hi guy's how to pass the value of datepicker into another textbox while clicking the datepicker value?
i have try something like this but my code not work.
maybe someone has try it. please help me,

this is the code that i have try

```js
$(function(){
    $('#date1').datepicker({
        onSelect:function(){
            $('#silo2').value();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
  <table>
       <tr>
         <td style="border:none"><label for="tanggal"> Tanggal</label></td>
            <td style="border:none"><label>:</label></td>
            <td style="border:none"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="date1" name="date1" placeholder="Tanggal Input" size="14"/></td>
            <td style="border:none"> <input type="text" id="silo2" name="silo2" maxlength="5" size=1  />
                </td>
            <td style="border:none"></td>
       </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: use on change event on the first datepicker to set the value on the second input

Comment: `onChange:` right? replace the `onSelect`?

Comment: You can follow the link, it will be answering your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195432/why-date-is-not-displaying-for-jquery-date-picker/47195870#47195870