# Why date is not displaying for jquery date picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Iam using date picker jquery and it is not displaying inside input field. My link is  https://jsfiddle.net/sbk2hd4c/10/ .

My code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My link is: https://jsfiddle.net/sbk2hd4c/10/

Thankyou in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

https://jsfiddle.net/sbk2hd4c/11/

You used your Id in **div** which should be in your **input** tag

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' >
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' />
```

Change the id for input as above. Div should have different id.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `changeDate` to the datepicker and can set the date in textBox

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker().on('changeDate', dateChangeListener);

function dateChangeListener(event) {
    var formattedDate = event.format('dd.mm.yy');
    $('text_box_id').val(formattedDate);
}
```